# SQL Select date from second table if id matches

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables Security and CallPut. Security (table1) contain security_id and maturity_date (non noll values) and CallPut(table2) which has security_id and Odate (which are non null values which contains date time format values)
I want to select all rows from security(table 1) but in maturity_date i want value from odate column instead of maturity_date where security id exists in Callput(table2) and matches with security table

Eg
Security(table1)

```
Security_id|Maturity_date
abcd        25Jan2020
bcde        25jan2021
```

Callput(tabble2)

```
Security_id|Odate
abcd        25Jan2015
```

Required Output

```
Security_id|Maturity_date
abcd        25Jan2015 (since here id is there in callput it takes odate)
bcde        25jan2021 (since here id is not there in callput it takes maturity date)
```

I use oracle sql 
Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select s.Security_id, nvl(c.odate, s.Maturity_date) as Maturity_date
from Security s
left join
Callput c
on
s.Security_id = c.Security_id
```

p.s. just noticed it was an Oracle question, my code is for MS SQL Server
EDIT: corrected for Oracle syntax.

Comment: is there a way to do it with coalesce also? just curious cos i tried with it many times but could not do it.

Comment: @user2177784 can't speak for Oracle, but in MS SQL ISNULL() is basically the same as COALESCE() with 2 paremeters

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    s.Security_id,
    NVL(c.Odate, s.Maturity_date) Maturity_date
from 
    security s left join callput c 
    on (c.security_id = s.security_id);
```

Comment: hi, i was reading a bit more about nvl, isnt it used to replace null values only. will it work for non null values as well. please advice

Comment: If you want to replace non null values you have to look for 'case when' clause in PL/SQL. Try to edit your question to be more specific and I or someone else will try to answer. Outer (left) joining the two tables, will generate nulls in the case on non correspondent match, so I used the NVL.

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.* from security as s left join callput as c on (c.security_id = s.security_id);
```

Untested but you want to use a join. You can learn more about joins in Oracle's extensive documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm